# Increase size of / partition when it's in an extended partition already and the free space is outside it?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I have run out of space on my / partition (running ubuntu 14.04LTS). Since I don't use the windows partition I've reduced it so I can increase the size of my /. Since the / is in an extended partition I'm not sure how to go about moving it, does it have to be to the right side of it? Will this cause me hassle with grub? Also how big should I make my / partition?

I have included a screenshot of my gparted.

[image]

Comment: You can't extend a partition **backwards** without the program literally rewriting almost all the data to the disk. That is a procedure with a big risk of data loss

Comment: You can expand the extended partition first, and then expand the partitions within it.

Comment: If the unallocated space were after your partition, it would be doable. But in your case your unallocated space is behind it. I suggest formatting the unallocated space as an extra files partition.

Comment: Sorry for my cluelessness, would formatting it as an extra files partition help with my lack of space on the / partition?

Comment: @mmm There's no such thing as an "extra files partition", I think what he meant is just creating a new partition to mount somewhere, but that complicated things if you mount your /opt or /var folders.  It looks like either way, you'll be moving lots of data and should definitely make a backup of the entire disk before doing anything.  You could create a new partition and copy-and-paste your sda5 partition into the unallocated space, make it larger, and then make that your root (/) folder.  Do this using a LiveCD/USB. But you would have to delete one of your primary partitions like the sda1/2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be tricky... so BACKUP BACKUP BACKUP first!

Assuming that you don't need/want to mess with your unallocated space...

1. boot to a Live CD and start gparted

   1.2 select sda6 and issue a swapoff command
2. reduce your sda7 partition by say 40GB to 50GB
3. move sda7 as far to the right as possible

   3.5 enlarge sda6 to 32GB
4. assuming that your swap is large enough already, move sda6 to the right
5. extend sda5 to the max (~+30GB)

   5.1 select sda6 and issue a swapon command
6. reboot

I would do this in single steps, rather than entering all commands at the same time and clicking the apply button.

Comment: Thanks. Is it better to not interfere with the unallocated space then? I was gonna use is so I didn't use up all the space I have for /home?

Comment: Your /home is only about 50% used, so there's no hurry to use the unallocated space yet. After performing my suggestion, you can always come back later and move sda4 and then enlarge sda7. Worry about fixing the sda5 and sda6 problem first. How much RAM do you have? sda6 should be about 1-1.5 times RAM size.

Comment: The output of "free -m" in the terminal gives total as is 32118 with 18826 used and 13291 free, so 32Gb?? I should have made these all bigger when initially setting up the computer but I was under instructions then to make it half windows.

Comment: Then make it at least 32118. Insert step 3.5 above, to extend sda6 before moving it. You'll also have to adjust my 20GB recommendation to something like 40GB to accommodate the larger swap partition.

Comment: Last thought... even after booting to the LiveCD, your current swap partition sda6 may be in use, so insert a step 3.2 select sda6 and issue a swapoff command in gparted.

Comment: Make that swapoff command step 1.2.

Comment: Status please. Cheers, Al

Comment: Still backing up, want to be careful that I can recover stuff once if this doesn't work.

Comment: Worked perfectly.

Comment: If you'd like, please post the latest gparted map for me to admire! Also, please rate my answer. Thanks!

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/xM40I This is my new gparted! I accepted it and upvoted it, is that the same thing?

Comment: I also issued swapon to sda6 before reboot.

Comment: Oh Oh. You made your swap 238GB instead of 32GB! Now your sda7 is short. You'll need to use the same steps to reduce sda6 swap, move sda7 to the left, then increase sda7. Upvoting and accepting are different, and it's nice to do both! Thanks!

Comment: ps: Did you also intentionally make sda5 so much larger? I was shooting for around 40-50GB, and it's 108GB now. It's OK, just bigger.

Comment: ps2: When resizing or moving a partition, sometimes it's easier to use the grab handles on the left/right sides of the graphic representation of the partition to resize, and the hand icon in the middle of the graphic representation to move a partition. Just watch the numeric representation to get you close, or to fine tune.

Comment: I wanted to have the sda5 nice and big, I didn't realise I was making the swap so large, I googled conversion between the units it was in and GB and thought I was making it 32GB, I'd best go and reduce it now.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/Oghfh Thankyou.

Comment: That looks MUCH better. Now later, if you need more space for sda7, you'll want to move sda4 left, enlarge sda4, and enlarge sda7. Make sense... now that you're an expert at this :-)